# How to draw custom shaped surface in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying do make a surface in Compose that has a custom shape like this:
[image]

But I have no idea how to make that top left part.

Even if I tried to use 2 surfaces next to each other it wouldn't work because of the elevation effect.

Comment: You should draw it somewhere (like Figma/Illustrator?) and export it as SVG, then you import it into android project as drawable. Then set it as background of Surface

Answer (score 1):

If the size of the header is the same for your items, just create an object expresion of `Shape` and pass it to `Modifier.clip(..)` and if the size is variable, I suggest you research about `Custom layout in Compose`.

Comment: What about using a Drawable?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky You should use 9-patch png

Comment: These days everybody uses SVG's.  I haven't seen a 9-patch in six years :)

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Being less used does not mean that it is not suitable, although with svg it is not possible to determine which part is stretched, the only solution is to use canvas or 9-patch.